# Analysis of Deviance in R returns a significant factor, but the mean of each group does not show any difference

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

We performed a 45s test with dogs and humans, we measured the distance between the dog and the human every 0.25seconds with GPS.

The data for one subjects are in the following format:

| Subject_Id | distance | Breed | walk_cond | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | molossoid | slow | 0.00 |
| 1 | 1.1 | molossoid | slow | 0.25 |
| 1 | 1.2 | molossoid | slow | 0.50 |
| 1 | 0 | molossoid | static | 0.75 |
| 1 | 0.5 | molossoid | static | 1.00 |
| 1 | 0.2 | molossoid | static | 1.25 |
| 1 | 2 | molossoid | fast | 1.50 |
| 1 | 2.5 | molossoid | fast | 1.75 |
| 1 | 2.2 | molossoid | fast | 2.00 |

We want to see the effect of the following factors on the distance :

- Breed (2 levels)
- HP : number of humans (2 levels)
- walk_cond : human's walking pace (3 levels)

which led us to the following linear mixed model:

```
GPS=read.csv("D:MyCSV.csv",header=TRUE,sep=';',dec=",")
contrasts(GPS$Breed)<-"contr.sum"
contrasts(GPS$HP)<-"contr.sum"
contrasts(GPS$walk_cond)<-"contr.sum"
mdist = lme(distance~walk_cond*Breed*HP, random = ~1|Subject_ID,data=GPS, correlation = corCAR1(form=~time|Subject_ID))

summary(mdist)
Anova(mdist,type=3)
```

The result is the following:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III tests)

Response: distance
                     Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)        97.5753  1    < 2e-16 ***
walk_cond           0.3894  2    0.82308    
Breed               3.9086  1    0.04804 *  
HP                  4.2323  1    0.03966 *  
walk_cond:Breed     2.1892  2    0.33468    
walk_cond:HP        0.5100  2    0.77493    
Breed:HP            1.0983  1    0.29463    
walk_cond:Breed:HP  1.0298  2    0.59757    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I computed the mean and the standard deviation using ddply hoping to see a difference on my two groups for the Breed factor but I found the following result:

```
> ddply(GPS,~Breed, summarise,distance.mean=mean(distance),distance.sd=sd(distance))
      Breed distance.mean distance.sd
1 molossoid      4.835714    5.037549
2  shepherd      4.824046    5.430650
```

My questions are the following:

- Is it normal to have an effect on the factor that does not show in the mean and standard deviation ? If it is the case, how should I visualize my difference ?
- Is there an issue with my model that could explain this discrepency between my results ?

Comment: Your computations are unrelated.  The analysis of deviance table controls for the effects of many factors but the simple summary does not.  There's no reason for them to give even remotely similar results.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand the difference between both now, but since the analysis of deviance takes into account all other factors is there a way to graphically display this ?

Comment: Which aspect of it do you wish to display?

Comment: I saw in some articles that when there is a significant effect for a factor,  the difference between the levels of these factors is displayed with a bar plot, that's why I was trying to plot the means.
Sorry if it is a trivial matter, i'm a student and a beginner in statistics.

Comment: It's far from trivial.  I'm just trying to figure out what you want to do.  Sure, you can plot the group means: but that's not going to help much with visualizing the results of your regression model.